# VueJs component not getting data from its parent instance

Tags: components, vue.js

I am new to VueJS and I am confused why a simple example from the docs is not working for me.

This is all the code. I am expecting it to display "Howdie Partners" on the page.

#### HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <greeting></greeting>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
Vue.component('greeting', {
    template: '<h1>{{message}}</h1>',
    props: ['message']
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: "Howdie Partners!"
  }
});
```

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/hq1yu0ct/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props):

> we can also use v-bind for dynamically binding props to data on the parent. Whenever the data is updated in the parent, it will also flow down to the child.

So you need to pass the props in the `greeting` component like following:

```
<div id="app">
  <greeting :message="message"></greeting>
</div>
```

check working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hq1yu0ct/1/).

Comment: Odd I didn't see that mentioned in the docs... is there perhaps another more typical way?

Comment: @CodyBugstein added link of documentation as well.